# Create an automator script to create folder + move files into created folder

Tags: finder, automator, script

Looking to create a service in Automator so when I select multiple files in the Finder, I can in one right-click create a new folder and move the selected files into that newly created folder. This action could include a step that will ask me to name this folder but it's not mandatory. Any idea?

Comment: You asked "Any idea?", well sure but what have you tried?

Comment: Automator > New > Service | setting Service receives selected _files or folders_ in _Finder_ | add a Move Finder Items _action_, setting Options to: Show this action when the workflow runs

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). You may also want to read [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution.

Not sure if you're aware of this but there's already a keyboard shortcut in Finder, (control + command + N) which creates a new folder containing the selected finder items.  This can also be accessed through the contextual menu when right clicking on selected Finder items.

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But for stability and compatibility reasons, I am still with High Sierra.

Comment: This solution works like a charm: https://hbase.net/2011/08/17/move-selected-files-into-a-new-folder-using-applescript-and-automator/

Comment: Sometimes you want to create a new Folder with only one item (e.g. so you can add more later) and then—doesn't work …